# Why is some of my JQuery loading right away, and other parts are taking over ten minutes to load on a page (or never loading)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm developing a web-page, basically from scratch. I have a .html file, .css file, and .js file that includes only JQuery. I am only running this locally on my own machine, and for some reason, now only some of my Javascript loads. For instance, I have some hidden s that when hovered over, they are displayed with JQuery calls. These seem to work fine as they always have. I have a scrolling sidebar that has hidden sub-menu items, and this usually loads fine as well. I have a hidden div that displays a definition list on a button click, and when you hover over the , the  should slideDown. If I wait about 10-15 minutes this will start working. But obviously that is a problem.

Also, in Chrome's 'Developer Tools' I don't see any errors under the sources tab. I checked the 'Pause on caught exceptions' box, (this is where my knowledge ceases) and in jquery.min.js:formatted, it pauses and highlights `e.querySelectorAll("*,:x"),` and when I resume, it does the same thing here, `c.call(e, "[s!='']:x"),`

Hoping someone can not only answer my question, but explain what's going on here in the caught exceptions. By the way, I did not write jquery.min.js:formatted.

Thanks in advance!

I copy/pasted my link to fontawesome and the JQuery library is up to date. Someone said something about the possibility of an infinite loop, but I'm not keen on what that is, I'll look into it.

Showed some code above. Not sure how helpful it is.

My expected output would obviously be for my JQuery to work, but it is not.

No error messages in the Console.

Comment: Please post a working example that demonstrates the problem after reading: [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Put a breakpoint in chrome console on button hover/click event, or whatever is taking along time, see what happens

Answer (score 0):

I actually figured it out, sorry I can't post working examples bc it's proprietary.

I was missing a closing `}` bracket...

But the way I figured this out was through opening up Chrome's 'Developer Tools' and switching into the 'Sources' tab.
- From here, underneath the stop sign with a pause symbol, it displayed exceptions in the code where something breaks.

This was much easier than scanning the code with my eyes. Sorry if this was a basic answer, it really helped me a lot.